# count down that does not reset on page refresh

Tags: jquery, counter, countdown

I found this count down timer code here http://jsfiddle.net/QH6X8/ I would like to make 3 additions if possible.

1. How can I make it so that the count down does not reset and start all over if the visitor reloads the page.
2. In the code it has `var end = new Date('15 Jul 2011');` How can I make it so that it is counting down to a specific hour instead of day(s) like this `var end = new Date('15 Jul 2011 1:00 PM PDT');`
3. Lastly after the count down is finished I would like it to display some text `Your time is up!`.

Comment: The second part of your question might answer the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, use cookies. A full tutorial can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

For the second: `var end = new Date('15 Jul 2011 1:00 PM PDT');`

Well it already looks like you know how to use setInterval, so, instead of continuing to modify the timer, use `document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 
"Your time is up"` So that takes care of 3.

Comment: lol 2 was already answered :P thanks for the help i think i can manage 1 but can you explain 3 a little more?